# Formula for the modulus of $Az$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I was wondering if there's a formula to calculate $|Az|$ for $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ invertible and $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Here, I denoted with $|w|=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n|w_j|^2}$ if $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$. I mean, a formula as $|Az|=C|z|$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, yes: $\sqrt{z^HA^HAz}$.

Comment: the square root

Comment: Well, this is obvious, I meant something like $|Az|^2=C|z|^2$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @UnusualMathem Nah, that ain't happening.

Comment: What you *do* have is inequalities with the (various) norms of $A$ involved.

Answer (score 1):

To see why it isn't possible, consider the simple case of $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
If $z = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, Then $|Az| = |z|$, but if $z = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, then $|Az| = 2|z|$.

Matrices can have different magnification effects in different directions, so you have to account for all independent directions in your formula. And the simplest way to do that is with matrices. So $\sqrt{z^HA^HAz}$ is really about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation :D